# How to respond when something floods inside home

Tags: dishwasher, flooding

The dishwasher flooded and I didn't know what to do. I guess the first step in dealing with a flood is cutting off the source of water, right? I opened up the dishwasher door which caused it to shut off the water. How do you clean up the water? We didn't have many tools handy, we had a small mop which was insufficient but found using the dust broom to sweep the water out of the house worked alright, though now the water carried with it a bunch of garbage which collected at our door step. Are there any tools that are worthwhile to buy encase of a flood like this?

Answer (score 4):

Water damage isn't easy to deal with, here are the steps off the top of my head:

1. Shutoff the water
2. Get the water out, via floor drains, buckets, submersible pump, or a shop vac. I'd recommend the shop vac for being a fairly handy tool everyone should own.
3. Dry the area, and remove anything damaged by the water. Use fans, open windows, and/or dehumidifiers to dry it out. I would completely remove carpeting, drywall, 
   fiberglass insulation, finishing woodwork (trim), and probably plywood/OSB that has absorbed water. Appliances, duct work, and utility lines should also be inspected.
4. Clean and treat the area to prevent mold. This means bleach and other mold killers.
5. Replace anything that's been damaged.

As for the flooding dishwasher, make sure that the float sensor in the bottom of the dishwasher is always moving freely, and avoid running it when you're going to be away. Objects can get lodged under this float, preventing the dishwasher from filling. If something ever holds the float down, then it won't stop filling since the float is indicating that there isn't any water in the bottom.

Comment: Is a shop vac the same as a wet/dry vacuum?

Comment: Shop vac is usually the same as a wet/dry vac (and you want one that works in wet situations, which means you can remove the filter and there will be a float to stop water from getting into the motor). You want something with a large canister that's measured in gallons, not a small handheld dustbuster.

Comment: Excellent answer.  More urgent than getting the water off (the middle of) the floor would be keeping the water from spreading (or continuing to spread) under cabinets, or spreading to the walls, or spreading to adjoining carpeted areas, by using lots of bath towels, bedding, clothes, etc, around the perimeter.

Comment: [Shop Vac](http://www.shopvac.com/) is a brand name wet/dry vacuum.